# JS - Check *all* selected files on dragenter, error if any do not meet requirement

Tags: javascript

I have a drag and drop image "uploader" (it does not upload, only converts to base64 and displays thumbnails). Currently if you drag one file into the dropzone, if it is not a .jpg/.jpeg it will show error (this is correct functionality), but if you drag multiple files into the dropzone, it does not show the error if at least 1 file is a jpg, even if the other file(s) do not meet jpg requirement, which is not what should happen (ex: you select .jpg and .zip, this will not trigger error, but it should). I need to show the error always unless all selected files are .jpg.  Can anyone assist?

Here is the relevant dragenter code (same code for dragover)

```
container.addEventListener(
"dragenter",
(e) => {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
const img = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.items).find(e => e.type.match('image/jpeg'))
if (img){
   container.classList.add("active");
}else{
  error.innerHTML = "HTML removed from snippet for readability";
  error.classList.remove("hideit");}
},
false
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x2fyrcLb/2/

Comment: Well, at the moment you are just looking for all the jpeg images. You probably could compare the length of `img` array and the `e.dataTransfer.items` and show the error, if they are not the same.

Comment: @Geshode Very good idea, I will try to implement that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing "`find`" to "`every`" (search MDN documentation for "`Array.prototype.every`"):

```
const img = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.items).every(e => e.type.match('image/jpeg'))
```

There's another array method, `some`, for checking "if at least one".

Comment: this worked perfectly, can't believe i just needed to change that one word. That's exactly what I needed, thank you very much.